# C++ Path to the directory given its name

Tags: c++

I'm writing a C++ program in Linux and I would need to change the current directory. I have a name of the directory I want to change it on, and I    want to use the chdir(). But it's argument is a path (i.e. the char* containing the directory location). And I don't have the full path, but just the name of directory.

I've seen this question: [Changing the current directory in Linux using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747014/changing-the-current-directory-in-linux-using-c)

However, I think that the proposed solution works only if the new directory is the sub directory of the current directory - otherwise, it doesn't make a sense for me if there can be more different directories of the same name in my computer (please, tell me if I'm wrong).

I'm not sure if I'm clear, to be sure, here is the example:

```
-CurrentDirectory
    |
    - Subdirectory
    |
    - ... etc.
- AnotherDirectory
```

In my opitnion, if I want change the current directory to Subsirectory, `chdir(Subdirectory.c_str())` would work. But not `chdir(AnotherDirectory.str())` (which has nothing in common with CurrentDirectory in general). 
 I know this question has to be already answered somewhere, but I'm not able to find it.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Check `boost::filesystem` or the new functions in the standard library for the upcoming c++17 standard.

Comment: [chdir](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) "The current working directory is the starting point for interpreting relative pathnames (those not starting with '/')." So `/` at the beginning for absolute path, `../` to go up one, `../../` to go up two, etc.

Comment: How do you know what directory to change to? Where does that information come from? You have either a relative path to it or an absolute path to it, otherwise you have a disembodied name that could relate to any one of thousands of directories in different places with the same name.

Comment: Can you provide some code that illustrates what you have and what you are trying to do? Right now I find it rather unclear.

Comment: It isn't quite clear what `getFilePath` you have in mind. It doesn't look like there's such function in the Java platform. It is also unclear why you hope to be able to locate a directory or file by name without using any kind of path. If we could do that we would not need hierarchical file names.

Comment: @n.m : I'm sorry, you're right. getFilePath doesn't exist in Java platform, it's my function I've writen and I use it so often that I just believed it's a standard one. Sorry for this confusion, I've edited my question.

Comment: And then, I know that's unclear what I'm looking for. To be more precise, I have a Java code in directoryA that calls the C++ executable placed in directoryB which uses some files from that directoryB. But as the C++ executable is called from the Java file, the current directory is directoryA. Of course, I know the path to the both directories. For instant, I stock it in a constant and I use chdir with this constant. But i just don't find this solution nice, so I asked myself if I could know the directoryB path "automatically", without the constant.

Comment: @kilpikonna: Don't comment your own question, but do **edit your question** to improve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you might have *several* sub-directories (in various directories) sharing the same name (so you could have both `a/xx/` and `b/c/xx/`)

You could use [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) to find something in a file tree and [getcwd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcwd.2.html) to get the current directory. You could also consider using [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html), [closedir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/closedir.3.html) to scan one directory (and build complete paths to be passed to [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html))

Then, to get some "canonical" path, consider using [realpath(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html)

Notice that [glob(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html) (see also [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html)), [fnmatch(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html), [wordexp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html) could be useful too.

Comment: Thank you for a very clear and straightforward response. I knew getcwd and realpath, but I didn't know nftw(3) and it seems it is what I was looking for. This helped me!

Comment: @kilpikonna "it seems it is what I was looking for" Either you are mistaken or your design is totally broken.

Answer (score 2):

You could use getcwd to get the absolute path name of the current directory.

```
#include <unistd.h>

char * getcwd(char *buf, size_t bufsize);
```

To change to another directory, you need know either the absolute path to the other direrctory, or its relative path to it such as ../someotherdirectory

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to "search" for a directory by name.  I suggest using the `locate` database for this.  You can try it on the command line:

```
locate AnotherDirectory
```

This will print all the files and directories on your local disks which are indexed.

Using this database could improve performance a lot if you don't know where to look for this directory.  You can read about where to find the underlying file here: https://serverfault.com/questions/454127/where-is-the-updatedb-database-located - but you could also just use `popen()` to run the `locate` program for a more portable solution than directly reading the database files.

Of course you will still need to write application logic to deal with multiple directories having the same name and so on.

Comment: I don't think that forking a process is sensible in this case. [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) could be more relevant

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Well you can read the DB directly--it's just a file.  However, I don't love the `nftw()` solution if it means traversing a lot of directories.  The DB solution is just an indexed lookup which if you have a large filesystem could be hugely more efficient.